# bluebird throws unhandled rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, q

When I write `promise` in variable, I am getting `unhandled rejection`:

```
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');

const p = Promise.reject(new Error('qwerty'));
```

> Unhandled rejection Error: qwerty
>           at Object.

but when I'm doing the same thing with `q`, error is not thrown:

```
'use strict';

const q = require('q');

const p = q.reject(new Error('qwerty'));
```

Why does `Promise.reject` in bluebird work this way? I can't find information in documentation about this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled rejection error Bluebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817407/unhandled-rejection-error-bluebird)

Comment: Bluebird will fall back on native `Promise` if it is available which has this behavior. I'm not sure that `q` does the same sort of thing.

Comment: But it does, you can check it

Comment: Perhaps because Bluebird has more warnings about likely problems in your code?  You have a rejected promise with no `.catch()` handler.  That's considered a problem.